# .htaccess remove index.php from subdir redirects all dynamic pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

Trying to remove index.php from and just resolve to the subdirectory name which works, however after making the change to .htaccess file all the other pages redirect to the subdirectory.

For example:
Changed: `site.com/subdir/index.php` to `site.com/subdir/` 
but then `site.com/subdir/page?id=4` resolves to `site.com/subdir/`

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteBase /subdir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

How to write this rule so that only index.php resolves to /subdir/ and not the other pages within that directory?

Comment: It is located in the root directory

Comment: Is there any .htaccess in `/subdir/` also?

Comment: There is no .htaccess file in `/subdir/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*/)index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ subdir/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! That was a big help!